# All subsets of $\{1,\{\}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to figure out what all subsets of the set $A \colon= \{1,\{\}\}$ are.
I am not sure if the answer is:

1. $P(A) = \{ \{ \}, \{1\}, \{1;\{\}\}, \{\{\}\} \}$ or
2. $P(A) = \{ \{\}, \{1\}, \{1; \{\}\} \}$

Comment: Friendly reminder that $\{\{\}\}\neq \{\}$.  Your concern between options 1 and 2 seems to have been that $\{\{\}\}$ didn't need to be included, perhaps because you think it didn't count as a subset of $A$ or because you thought that it already appeared in your list as the first item.  It is a subset and it is distinct from the first entry in your list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) is the set of all subsets of A, including the empty set and A itself therefore in this case

$$P(A) = \Big\{ \{\}, \{1\}, \{\{\}\}, \{1,\{\}\} \Big\}$$

which indeed, since $|A|=n=2$, has $2^n=4$ elements.

Comment: thats what I thought, thank you so much.

Comment: @heyhoe You are welcome! Bye